# Check a whole table for a single value

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, null, pattern-matching

**Background:** I'm converting a database table to a format that doesn't support null values.  I want to replace the null values with an arbitrary number so my application can support null values.

**Question:** I'd like to search my whole table for a value ("999999", for example) to make sure that it doesn't appear in the table.  I could write a script to test each column individually, but I wanted to know if there is a way I could do this in pure sql without enumerating each field.  Is that possible?

Comment: Do not put "sql" in the title, that is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a special feature of the PostgreSQL type system:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  t::text LIKE '%999999%';
```

There is a [composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rowtypes.html) of the same name for every table that you create in PostgreSQL. And there is a `text` representation for every type in PostgreSQL (to input / output values).

Therefore you can just cast the whole row to `text` and if the string '999999' is contained in any column (its `text` representation, to be precise) it is guaranteed to show in the query above.

You cannot rule out **false positives** completely, though, if separators and / or decorators used by Postgres for the row representation can be part of the search term. It's just *very* unlikely. And positively not the case for your search term '999999'.

There was a very similar question on codereview.SE recently. I added [some more explanation in my answer there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7231/9501).

Comment: Any particular reason you use `~~` instead of the standard LIKE operator?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No particular reason. You probably know that, but an odd fact for the general public: while being identical operators, `~~` ranks higher in [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) than `LIKE`. So the expression `'ab' LIKE 'a' || '%'` needs parentheses with `~~`: `'ab' ~~ ('a' || '%')`.

Comment: Thanks. No, I didn't know that about the operator precendence. I try to use standard SQL wherever possible (so I never use `~~`). That makes switching between SQL dialects easier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'd say that's good practice. I amended my example to support that (even though this is Postgres specific anyway). I find `~~` slightly easier to read, and easier to switch between `~` (regexp match) and `~~`, and I mostly work with PostgreSQL anyway, so I like the shorter operator.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm not really conversant with SQL, and except due to context, I didn't know what ~~ meant.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function test_values( real ) returns setof record as
$$
declare
query text;
output record;
begin
for query in select 'select distinct ''' || table_name || '''::text table_name, ''' || column_name || '''::text column_name from '|| quote_ident(table_name)||' where ' || quote_ident(column_name) || ' = ''' || $1::text  ||'''::' || data_type  from information_schema.columns where table_schema='public'   and numeric_precision is not null
loop
    raise notice '%1 qqqq', query;
    execute query::text into output;
    return next output;
end loop;
return;
end;$$ language plpgsql;

select distinct * from test_values( 999999 ) as t(table_name text ,column_name text)
```