# PL/pgSQL: General Way to Update N Columns in Trigger?

Tags: postgresql, types, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, triggers

I am attempting create a function that will take a general table and convert N columns to upper case. I haven't had any luck finding a solution to this type of problem, but I was able to come up with the following:

```
create or replace function uc_on_insert()
returns trigger as
$$
declare
p_tbl varchar = TG_TABLE_NAME;
p_sch varchar = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA;
i varchar;
begin
    for i in 

    (select column_name
    from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where 1=1
    and table_name ilike p_tbl
    and table_schema ilike p_sch
    and data_type ='character varying')

    loop
           execute 'new.' || i || ' = upper(new.' || i || ');';
       return new;
    end loop;

end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I'm currently getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "new"
LINE 1: new.c1 = upper(new.c1);
        ^
QUERY:  new.c1 = upper(new.c1);
```

The expected input would be, on any table I have this trigger:

```
insert into table_one('a', 'b');

>> A, B
```

and if I put this trigger on another table:

```
insert into table_two ('a', 3);
>> A, 3
```

etc.

Comment: new is a reserved word that has a very specific meaning within a trigger, so putting it inside '' will turn it into a string?

Comment: @JohnBarça: I'm attempting to create a series of statements with the new reserved word in it, so that expands to new.c1; new.c2; etc.

Comment: Also note the added "simple method".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very tricky question.

Your attempt is bound to fail, because the current row variable `NEW` is not visible inside `EXECUTE`. And even if it was, `NEW` is a row type (a record), not an array. Unlike array elements, fields of a row cannot be referenced by numerical index. This would cause all kinds of problems in SQL, because (as opposed to an array) each field can have a different data type, and SQL expects to *know* the data type to deal with beforehand. Very tricky indeed.

### Generic method targeted at selected types only

Fortunately, we have dealt with a similar problem before:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711432/how-to-set-value-of-composite-variable-field-using-dynamic-sql)

You'll find ample explanation there.
Adapted for a trigger function and depending on the data type of columns, it could look like this:

#### Trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_uc_on_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || array_to_string(ARRAY(
      SELECT CASE WHEN atttypid = 'varchar'::regtype
                    -- atttypid = ANY('{text, bpchar, varchar}'::regtype[])
                THEN 'upper(($1).' || quote_ident(attname)
                                   || ')::' || atttypid::regtype::text 
                ELSE '($1).' || quote_ident(attname)
             END AS fld
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = pg_typeof(NEW)::text::regclass
      AND    attnum > 0
      AND    attisdropped = FALSE
      ORDER  BY attnum
      ), ',')
USING  NEW
INTO   NEW;

RETURN NEW;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you want to apply the same rule to other basic character types as well, use the commented alternative.

#### Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_t_insbef
BEFORE INSERT
ON t              -- works for any table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_uc_on_insert();
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0eaa2/1)

### Simple, unspecific method

As long as you are using simple types in your tables only and want to upper-case **all character data**, there is another crude, fast and simple method: Cast the whole row to `text`, upper-case the text representation, cast back to the row type and update `NEW` with the result. Details about the row type of a table

- [Check a whole table for a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994830/check-a-whole-table-for-a-single-value/9995522#9995522)

Trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_uc_simple_on_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE 'SELECT ($1::' || pg_typeof(NEW) || ').*'
   USING upper(NEW::text)
   INTO NEW;

RETURN NEW;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7e99c/1)

We have to decompose the row type, because `SELECT INTO` assigns individual fields of a target row type one-by-one. We cannot assign the whole row at once. If you look closely, the "generic" solution does the same, less obvious.

While character data is case-sensitive in text representation, other basic numeric or date / time data types are not. So the simple method works reliably. Probably with most other types, too. But I did not test with others, and there certainly are exception. You'll have to **verify for the data types you use.**

Also, while the code is much shorter and simpler than with the generic method, this is not necessarily faster, especially with lots of unaffected columns. It's probably a lot faster in simple cases, though.

Comment: +1. I didn't realize you could do multiple casting like this: atttypid::regtype::text

Comment: This is incredible. We are totally blown away by this answer, and we learned quite a few things just from breaking down all that your code does. Just wonderful and one of the best answers I've seen in a while.

Comment: @dizzystar: Thank you. This wasn't a shot from the hip. *A lot* of thought and optimization work went into the related answer I linked to. Your question could tap into that.

Comment: @JohnBarça: Strictly speaking `atttypid::regtype` would be enough in the example above, because the [object identifier type `regtype`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) is coerced to `text` when concatenated automatically. Just being clear. The wicked twist is that the cast produces the text representation of the type used in the next cast in the dynamic SQL ...