# In PostgreSQL, I want a before insert trigger to dynamically change blanks into valid UUIDs

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have been looking at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154599/3810920) as a basis for this trigger.

I need to do a large import of several tables with several UUID fields, which were formerly stored as `char(35)` in MySQL, some of which are blank ('').

I'd like to automatically change blanks to nil UUIDs using a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER.

Currently I have the trigger function simplified to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_uc_on_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'in function';
    NEW.id=uuid_generate_v1();
    RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I'm running

```
create table uuidtest (id uuid);
insert into uuidtest values ('');
```

but I am still getting

```
[Err] ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: ""
LINE 1: insert into uuidtest values ('');
```

I have too much data to import and I would much rather let PostgreSQL change the values before the insert than do it myself.

Is this possible using this mechanism, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sure. You just need a `BEFORE` trigger that tests for `NEW.id = ''` and if so, sets `NEW.id := uuid_generate_v4()` before returning `NEW`. See the trigger examples in the PostgreSQL manual for details on `BEFORE` triggers.

Comment: @CraigRinger The error is apparently generated before the trigger function is entered. Without knowing the details of the code, this presumably is because the `NEW` record has the `uuid` type for id and can thus not be populated with an empty string.

Comment: @Patrick Ah, that makes sense. Because it's not `NULL`, it's an invalid UUID `''`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL a `uuid` is stored in binary form, hence an empty string is invalid as a `uuid` value.

The easiest approach is probably to import the tables with a `char(35)` column, then `UPDATE` blank values to a text representation of of a `nil` `uuid` and then `ALTER COLUMN` to convert the column to the `uuid` data type.

Assuming you have your import done, do:

```
UPDATE my_table SET id = '00000000000000000000000000000000' -- that's 32 0's
WHERE id = '';
```

The above is a true `nil` `uuid`.

Now you can change the column to the [`uuid` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html). Provided all text values are in a format PostgreSQL can understand, the values will be converted to `uuid` automatically:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER id TYPE uuid;
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the answer was right! I was afraid of some performance impact after changing table column types.