# Error: column does not exist in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, set-returning-functions

Trying to create a function that will return multiple rows from a table if a `searchTerm` exists anywhere inside one of the columns. (I am new to Postgres.)

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dts_getProjects(searchTerm TEXT) RETURNS SETOF project
 AS $$
 SELECT credit_br AS Branch, status FROM job_project
 WHERE credit_br LIKE '%'||searchTerm||'%'
 $$
 language 'sql';
```

I get this error:

> ```
>  ERROR:  column "searchTerm" does not exist
>  LINE 3: ...status FROM job_project WHERE credit_br LIKE '%'||searchTerm||'...
> ```

Comment: Please remember to always provide your version of Postgres and the exact table definition of relevant tables. Hint: `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dts_get_projects(_search_term text)
  RETURNS SETOF job_project AS
$func$
SELECT j.*
FROM   job_project j
WHERE  j.credit_br ILIKE '%' || _search_term || '%'
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

I am using the table type to return whole rows. That's the safe fallback since you did not disclose any data types or table definitions.

I also use `ILIKE` to make the search case-insensitive (just a guess, you decide).

This only searches the *one* column `credit_br`. Your description sounds like you'd want to search all columns (`anywhere inside one of the columns`). Again, most of the essential information is missing. A very quick and slightly dirty way would be to search the whole row expression converted to `text`:

```
...
WHERE  j::text ILIKE '%' || _search_term || '%';
...
```

Related:

- [Check a whole table for a single value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994830/check-a-whole-table-for-a-single-value/9995522#9995522)

Asides:
Don't use mixed-case identifiers in Postgres if you can avoid it.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Don't quote the language name of functions. It's an identifier.

Comment: Hi Erwin, isnt begin end required? Since I am getting this error http://pasteboard.co/22ZD5izR.jpg

Comment: @bluepiranha: `BEGIN` and `END` are required for `LANGUAGE plpgsql`, but not for `LANGUAGE sql`. The error you get indicates you are on a very old version of Postgres, where SQL functions did not accept parameter names. You can use `$1` in the function body instead.